# SGDClassifier with predict_proba

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn libraries for training and testing my data.

```
targetDataCsv =  pd.read_csv("target.csv","rt"))
testNormalizedCsv = csv.reader(open("testdf_new.csv","rt",encoding="utf-8"))
traningNormalizedCsv = pd.read_csv("traindf_new.csv", skiprows=1,nrows=99999)
df = pd.read_csv("testdf_new.csv", skiprows=1, nrows=9999)
```

I wanted to use partial_fit method of SGDClassifier since my training data has more than 200000 rows.

```
 X = traningNormalizedCsv.values
 y = targetDataCsv.values   
 clf = SGDClassifier()
 clf.partial_fit(X, y)
```

But this classifier does not have predict_proba method to get the target probability for my test data.

```
   clf.predict_proba(df.values)
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you can see in [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.predict_proba) - ***This method is only available for log loss and modified Huber loss.***

So you have to change your loss function.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
import numpy as np
X = np.random.random_sample((1000,3))
y = np.random.binomial(3, 0.5, 1000)
model = SGDClassifier(loss="modified_huber")
model.partial_fit(X, y, classes=np.unique(y))
print(model.predict_proba([[0.5,0.6,0.7]]))
```

output for example: [[ 0.  0.  1.  0.]]